# Where to get data(images) to learn models and analytics in 2023 (Data science / ML / DL)

Tags: image, machine-learning, web-scraping, dataset, data-science

I have a question for you, but the answer may be completely different.
Maybe there is a completely different solution.

I wonder how data for Data Science / ML / DL projects is obtained in 2023.
I'm wondering where to get data sets (images) for portfolio projects.

The first thing that comes to my mind is:

1. Download ready-made data sets from the Internet (e.g. keggel, CIFAR-10, etc...).
2. Scrap websites, e.g. google-search-image to download images (using python+selenium).

Are there other ways?

For example, this not-so-serious example:

- Needs lots of pictures of pens to sort them into categories and to teach the algorithm to recognize the type of pens.
  But that's just an example, it might as well be the types of sunsets, or recognizing the types of ice cream, etc...

The answer will probably depend on what exactly you want to achieve.
But still, what do you think are good ways to obtain such image-data today?